# Linear search on a list?

Tags: python

I wrote this code for a simple linear search:

```
def floor(array, target):
    i = 0
    while i < len(array):
        if array[i] == target:
            print("The target value can be found at index: " + str(array[i]))
            break
        else:
            i = i + 1

floor([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 5)
```

The problem I'm having is that it's not returning the values I want. For some reason it doesn't start counting at 0, so when I make the target 1 it tells me the index is 1. Likewise, if I make the target 4 it will give me the second value of 4 at index 4 rather than the one at index 3. Even when the target is a higher number, it only seems to count the value of 4 once. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: For future reference, the built-in "index" method for lists can do this for you.  For example, [4,8,15,16,23,42].index(15) return 2.

Answer (score 2):

You're printing out the value at the index ie `array[i]` instead of `i`.

Comment: Geez, I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the value of the array at the index instead of the index itself.  This fixes it.  Also consider a return instead of a print statement.

```
def floor(array, target):
    i = 0
    while i < len(array):
        if array[i] == target:
            print("The target value can be found at index: " + str(i))
            return i
        else:
            i = i + 1

four_ind = floor([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4) # returns 3
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def floor(array, target):
    for i, value in enumerate(array):
        if value == target:
            print('target is in:', i)

floor([1,2,3,4,5, 4, 4,6], 4)
```